# Why @MockBean does not mock my target service class (returns real production instance)?

Tags: spring, mocking

Consider this setup

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@SpringBootTest
class FooTest {
    @MockBean
    UserService userService;

    @MockBean
    NotificationService notificationService;

    @Autowired
    Foo foo;

    @Test
    void testFoo() {
       ...
    }
}


@Service
class Foo {
   @Autowired
   UserService userService;
   @Autowired
   NotificationService notificationService;
}
```

So what's happening in `FooTest` is that `userService` has mockito mock injected into it, while `notificationService` gets the real class instance.

What may be the reason for this mis-behavior?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I noticed that `UserService` is an abstract class while the actual production type is a different class,
While `NotificationService` was a concrete implemantation.

Apparently `@MockBean` fails to mock an `@Autowired` component when the actual implementation is used within the calling service, instead of an abstract or interface.

After breaking `NotificationService` into `NotificationService` (interface) and `NotificationServiceImpl`, and making sure all services which use this component refers to the interface (as well as the test it self), finally I got a mockito mock injected inside every field of type `NotificationService` when running the test.